# Converting integer tuple to float

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-conversion

I have a tuple of integers. In reality, this is no tuple at all but a decimal number that all languages except English represent as *1,2* while English uses *1.2*. This "tuple" is read from a file and added into an array along with a series of integers, so the data type is automatically assigned by Python and I have no influence over it...

```
whatever[7] = 1,2
```

Is there some clever way of converting this to 1.2? I found ways but they only work on strings but when I convert this to string, it is parenthesised and split by a space,

```
str(whatever[7])
'(1, 2)'
```

...so the task gets expanded to getting rid also of "(", ")" and space, which is certainly feasible:

```
str(str(str(str(whatever[7]).replace(",",".")).replace(" ","")).replace("(", "")).replace(")","")
```

...but it does not exactly strike me with its beauty and elegance.

Comment: Are you importing your data file as though it were Python code? If so, why?

Comment: I am reading a csv file, then parsing it by "/n" and subsequently by ";", which leaves me with array (or list) where the only the last element can be the tuple. What I meant was that I do not define the variable in the beginning like *whatever = str(1,2)*, where I can choose the data type. Python does that and Python decides, this a tuple of integers.

Comment: But the last element won't be a tuple; it'll be a string. What are you doing to that string to end up with a tuple? Using `eval`? That's the code that you want to change.

Comment: Apart from anything else, consider what happens when your csv file contains the number `"-0,5"`. If you evaluate that as a tuple and then try to reinterpret as a float, you'll end up with `0.5`: the sign information has been irrevocably lost. A similar problem applies with `"2,03"`, which will get turned into `2.3` using this method (at least on Python 2). And if you're using `eval`, `"2,09"` will just end up giving you a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea why it gets read like a tuple since this is the first place where I do something with it. It is actually a time counter in seconds and I need to convert it to something like 0:00:15. To that end, I have to stringify, floatify and round. Plus I need to include exceptions for cases like ",001", which is also a possible value...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean like

```
print "%s.%s"%whatever[7]
```

And if you want to convert it to float

```
float("%s.%s"%whatever[7])
```

Comment: Ha, clever! It would never occur to me feed it to formatting.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your tuple to a float by first creating the string representation `'1.2'` and then feeding that to `float`.

To do that you could use `map` to cast `int`s to `str`s, join them on `'.'` and feed that to `float()`.

For example:

```
>>> t = 1, 2
>>> f = float(".".join(map(str,t)))
>>> print(f)
1.2
```

Answer (score 1):

The below format will work with your given example.

```
whatever[7] = 1, 2
new_num = float("{}.{}".format(whatever[7][0], whatever[7][1]))
```

Answer (score -1):

How about this?

```
>>> whatever = 1,2
>>> float('.'.join(str(num) for num in whatever))
1.2
```

Like Jim's answer, it creates a `str` representation of `'1.2'` but instead of using map, it creates a generator object (basically what's behind list comprehensions), which converts each item in `whatever` to string, that the `join` method can iterate over. Lastly, that string gets converted to a float type object